# Iterate over loop accessing two elements if they exist

Tags: ruby, loops, iterator

Well, I haven't found a clean solution to write this code easily in Ruby:

```
# Java style version:
array.each do |i, el|
  if i < array.length - 1
     process(array[i], array[i+1])
  end
end

# Would be nice if I could do something like this:
array.each do |i, el, next|
  process(el, next)
end
```

Comment: don't use `next` as variable, it's a flow control statement.

Comment: Thanks for the point @tokland, it was just a matter of example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`each_cons`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons):

```
array.each_cons(2) do |a, b|
  process(a, b)
end
```

Comment: Good ol' `each_cons` saves the day again!

Answer (score 2):

```
ar = [1,2,3,4]
(ar.size - 1).times {|i| process ar[i],ar[i+1]}
```